# Cannot find Configuration() in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, maven

I am going to create a simple `hibernateDAO` project,

But in `BookDao` class (which implements `bookDaoInterface`), I got this error in my `getSessionFactory()` method:

[image]

Here is project structure:

[image]

And this is maven `pom.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.sajjad</groupId>
    <artifactId>SimpleHibernateDAO</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>unknown-jars-temp-repo</id>
            <name>A temporary repository created by NetBeans for libraries and jars it could not identify. Please replace the dependencies in this repository with correct ones and delete this repository.</name>
            <url>file:${project.basedir}/lib</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.6.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>unknown.binary</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final</artifactId>
            <version>SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>unknown.binary</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin</artifactId>
            <version>SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
</project>
```

Hibernate configuration file (`hibernate.cfg`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">2323</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <mapping class="com.sajjad.simplehibernatedao.Book"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Assure that the file hibernate.cfg.xml is in your classpath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have a wrong or missing import. Make sure you have this import at the beginning:

```
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
```

and make sure that there is no other  `Configuration` class imported from a different package.